# Why this httpClient from Ionic 4 is not working?

Tags: youtube-api, ionic4

I tried to use Ionic 4 with Youtube Video Player, but I received this messages:

Follow the link of the repository:

[Github](https://github.com/victorc-developer/ionic4-youtube/tree/master/Ionic4Youtube)

[image]

[image]

Run ionic serve -l:

[image]

It's working well, run using ionic serve.

Comment: you need to subscribe to observable first then pipe it. So if you return observable like in your code - move pipe logic to the method that subscribed to the observable.

Comment: hm your code provided seems to have issues like  getListVideos method does not have arguments while you call it with an argument. Can you share full code of service and component?

Comment: I created the project to try simulate that problem.